# Locate Existing Numbers For Hyperlink In Textarea Set Next Avaibale One On Save / Click Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am using **CodeIgniter** & **jQuery** and **parsedown/markdown** When I open my bootstrap modal, it allows me to create a new Reference-style link like on here.

I am trying to be able to find some how where it can find the next free number for my available in my textarea and when click save in model will set it.

```
I am fine [exmple-1][1] and [example-3][3]

[1]: http://www.example.com
[3]: http://www.example.com
```

And when I open my bootstrap modal and create a new hyperlink it will set and add the next available number

Here is the [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/PbMzvo)

> **Question:** How can I when I create a new hyperlink in my bootstrap modal
>   and click save it can find the next available number set it. Because only 1 & 3 are set in example above next one should be 2 when click save in model

currently as you can see below I just use `var counter = 1;` and `counter++;` to be able to create numbers.

Script:

```
$('#myLink').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var text = getSelectedText();
    $('#title').val(text.trim());
    $('#url').val('http://');
});    

function getSelectedText() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("message");
    var len = textarea.value.length;
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
    return sel;
}

var counter = 1;

$('#save-link').on('click', function(e) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("message");
    var len = textarea.value.length;
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);

    var replace = '[' + $('input#title').val() + ']' + '[' + counter + ']';

    var id = '\n   [' + counter + ']: ' + $('input#url').val();

    counter++;

    if ($('#title').val().length > 0) {
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,start) + replace +
        textarea.value.substring(end,len) + ' \n' + id;
        $('#myLink').modal('hide');
        //$('#myLink form')[0].reset();
    } else {

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Where do you check whether the number is available? You just use `counter` without checking.

Comment: Yes just have been using var counter

Comment: I'm seeing a javascript exception here: $('#myLink form')[0].reset();

Comment: Use an object whose keys are the numbers that have been used. Write a loop that looks for the first number that isn't in the object.

Comment: Why do you not concatenate instead of replace the `.value` of `textarea`?

Comment: @Barmar not sue what you mean still learning jquery

Comment: How did `[2]` get skipped in the first place? Is there a button to delete an item in the middle of the list?

Comment: @wolfgang1983, instead of your textarea substr/replace operations and click counter (every click is counted) use something else...this doesn't work well: https://s29.postimg.org/fc7k8ux1j/bbb.jpg Store data to object, as suggested by Barmar, this is typicall key-value pair situation, and read/print from object...

Comment: This sounds like a solution in search of a problem. Why does it matter if the numbers are sequential? It looks like you're generating Markdown or something, in which case it shouldn't matter whether the numbers are sequential or not...

Comment: +1 for @MikeMcCaughan's comment. It doesn't really matter to store the sequence. In fact its an overhead for your program.

Comment: When I paste the copied links in it does not set the next correct number. Also

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple regex to find the used numbers in the textarea:

```
function findAvailableNumber(textarea){
    //Find lines with links
    var matches = textarea.value.match(/(^|\n)\s*\[\d+\]:/g);

    //Find corresponding numbers
    var usedNumbers = matches.map(function(match){
        return parseInt(match.match(/\d+/)[0]); }
    );

    //Find first unused number
    var number = 1;
    while(true){
        if(usedNumbers.indexOf(number) === -1){
            //Found unused number
            return number;
        }

        number++;
    }

    return number;
}
```

Add the function, remove the line `var counter = 1;` and replace `counter++;` with `var counter = findAvailableNumber(textarea);`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5h30ez3d/)

Comment: I did what you said but get matches null

Comment: Could not get it to work when click save on my bootstrap modal

Comment: Does not work for when I want to use my bootstrap modal will not let me create a link if non exist

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar said: store your already generated numbers in an object or an array and check for the next non-existing number:

```
var existingNumbers = [1, 3];

function getNextNumber() {
    var i = 1;

    while (existingNumbers.indexOf(i) > - 1) {
        i++;
    }

    existingNumbers.push(i);
    return i;
}
```

Then get the next number with:

```
var number = getNextNumber();
```

Comment: When click on save it show number 4 should start at 1. this `var existingNumbers = [1, 3];` for me.

Comment: It acutally should start with number 2. Number 4 is next, because I already added 1 and 3 to demonstrate that it skips them. If you want them to start at 1 you just need to empty existingNumbers: `var existingNumber = []`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 -- Is there any option to delete a link as well? If its there, this solution also needs to incorporate that.